# How can I use Pusher together with Awesome Notifications package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, pusher

I was trying to implement notifications in my flutter app.
I tried to use the package pusher (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pusher) where I wouldn't have any problems to use Pusher for my notification. Unfortunately, this package was breaking too many thing and I decided to go with awesome_notifications package(https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications).

Now everything works fine, but I have no idea how to connect Pusher using Awesome Notification package or any other package.

Does anybody know how to solve my issue?

Comment: https://pusher.com/ link to the Pusher

Answer (score 0):

To use awesome notifications along with Pusher Beams you would need to implement your own code to:

-register the device with Beams (using the API, documented at https://pusher.com/docs/beams/reference/device-api/)

-Associate a user ID, or subscribe to an interest (API endpoints for this also available in the above link)

-detect the receipt of a notification and then invoke Awesome Notifications to display the message. Beams uses the normal platform publish gateways, such as FCM and APNS, so Awesome Notifications should be able to handle this.

Comment: Can I have any code examples?